# For Loop that References the Previous Row in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I am relatively new to R and am trying to create a for loop with a conditional that references the previous row for equivalence. In order to learn to write this code for my own data, I created a simpler, representative data frame:

```
df<- c(1,1,2,0,0,0,0,1,1,2)
```

My goal would be to print a 1 for every value in df that is different from the previous value. For this df, this should look like:
[1] 0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1.

Here is what I have tried thus far:

```
for(i in df){
  if(x[i] != x[i-1]){
    print(1)
  }else{
    print(0)
  }
}
```

From the above code, I consistently get the error "argument is of length zero". Very possible that I am making a simple mistake, but I appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Try `for(i in 2:length(df)) {...}`.

Comment: R is a vectorized language. Try this instead of using a loop: `ifelse(df == dplyr::lag(df, default=-1), 1, 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this. You are using `x` which does not exist. Instead use `df` inside the loop. Also as you need comparison from one element to next, it would be better to start the loop from second position because the first element does not have any previous value to be compared. Here the code:

```
#Data
df<- c(1,1,2,0,0,0,0,1,1,2)
#Loop
for(i in 2:length(df)){
  if(df[i] != df[i-1]){
    print(1)
  }else{
    print(0)
  }
}
```

Output:

```
[1] 0
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 1
[1] 0
[1] 1
```