# R: Create a variable that uses value from previous row in a for loop

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to create a variable that takes on a value for a variable (z) when two rows differ on another variable (x). So if row numbers 1 and 2 differs for x (starting on row #2), I would like z to take the value of 1, otherwise 0.

I have tried with different if and if-else sentences based on this question ([For Loop that References the Previous Row in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64396299/for-loop-that-references-the-previous-row-in-r)), but it does not give me the desired results.

```
df <-
  data.frame(
    x = c(1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2),
    y = c(1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2),
    z = c(0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2)
  )

for (i in 2:length(df)) {
  df$z <- ifelse(df$x[i] != df$x[i - 1], 1, 0)
}


for (i in 2:length(df)) {
  if (df$x[i] != df$x[i - 1]) {
    df$z == 1
  } else{
    df$z == 0
  }
}
```

My expected results are:

```
df_expected <-
  data.frame(
    x = c(1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2),
    y = c(1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2),
    z = c(NA, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1)
  )
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Why is your expected second entry of `z == 1`? The first and second entries of `x` are both `1`?

Comment: I added 0, but NA could also work - the value for Z==1 does not matter for the rest of the analysis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**
If you need to use a `for`-loop, you could use

```r
df$z <- 0
for (i in 2:nrow(df)) {
  df[i, "z"] <- +(df[i, "x"] != df[i - 1, "x"])
}
```

The problem with your code is:

```
df$z == 1
```

doesn't assign anything, is a logical comparison.

---

You could use

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(z = +(x != lag(x, default = first(x))))
```

This returns

```r
   x y z
1  1 1 0
2  1 1 0
3  2 2 1
4  0 0 1
5  0 0 0
6  0 0 0
7  0 0 0
8  1 1 1
9  1 1 0
10 2 2 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I need it to be inside a for-loop as it is a part of a larger bunch of code?

Comment: @Mette Added a `for`-loop solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, z := as.integer(x != shift(x, fill = first(x)))]
```